# Using join table in a one to many association for legacy tables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations

I'm trying to marry a rails app to a related (and seriously crufty and wet) PHP app but having both apps share a database. So far it's working happily. I've encountered a case where I need a one to many relationship between a new model and a legacy one. Normally I'd simply use:

```
class LegacyModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :new_model
end

class NewModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :legacy_models
end
```

But in order do this I'd end up having to add a column to the legacy table and I'd rather not do that; the legacy app is fragile enough that I really don't want to risk altering its tables; just use them in a read only sense.  So I was considering using a join table where the `new_model_id` is unique and the `legacy_model_id` is not. This feels like I'm going off the Rails but I want that association fairly bad so I'm wondering if:

1) Is this an acceptable approach?

2) Are there any more better solutions?

Please note that my sample code is pseudo-code and not representative. I just want to get the idea across.

Thanks in advance for any help you can give me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a perfectly fine approach as far as I can see. Even if the model you were trying to connect to was a part of your current Rails app, having an explicit join table has many advantages (like being able to - either right away or later on - add more columns to it in order to add and capture more data).

I myself am working on something similar, but the other database I am touching is not a legacy, but quite new, except that I too only want to connect to it in a read only fashion, and so I make that similar join table. Nothing wrong with that!